# How to read .doc file page wise and extract images on that page?

Tags: java, apache-poi, document

I am able to extract all the pictures available in the .doc file using the below code -

```
doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File(this.file.getAbsolutePath())));
List<org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Picture> pictureList = new ArrayList<>();
pictureList = doc.getPicturesTable().getAllPictures();
```

and the total no of pages using the below snippet -

```
int pages = doc.getSummaryInformation().getPageCount();
```

Now i want to extract the pictures on the specific page, but not able to find a way around. Any how can we do it ?

Comment: Are you aware that, unlike PDF, the Word file format isn't actually a page based format?

Comment: Then I think that the alternate solution will be to convert doc into pdf and then iterate over it page wise. Any other solution for this ?